# Turn off Blazegraph inference

Tags: inference, blazegraph

When I add triples that use `rdfs:subPropertyOf`, Blazegraph adds a reflexive triple.  After doing some research, I came to the conclusion that I could turn off this behavior by going into the `blazegraph.properties` file and uncommenting this line:

`com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.axiomsClass=com.bigdata.rdf.axioms.NoAxioms`

I then deleted the journal and namespace my app is using, started up the service again, recreated the namespace, and tested to see if I could add a `subPropertyOf` triple without the extra triples being added in, and I still can't. Is there anything else I need to do? Or am I incorrect in thinking this behavior is inference?